# Apache POI throws encoding error when reading from File, but not from Stream

Tags: java, character-encoding, apache-poi

When loading a specific Excel (XLSX) file through Apache POI (3.17) in Java (7), I am getting an exception regarding encodings (`org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence`). This appears to be when reading the `sharedStrings.xml` file  (nb this file is encoded in UTF8).

However, if I load the file via an `InputStream` instead of a `File`, then the file loads correctly. In neither case am I (or can I) specify an encoding. I am aware that loading from an `InputStream` is not optimal and I am keen to avoid this.

I've written a small example to highlight my issue, although unfortunately I cannot share the problematic file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public class POIEncodingIssue
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final File file = new File("path\\to\\my\\file.xlsx"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Workbook workbook = null;

        // This works
        System.out.println("Trying Stream based approach..."); //$NON-NLS-1$
        try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file))
        {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(stream);

            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Value was \"{0}\"", workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (workbook != null)
            {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }

        // This doesn't
        System.out.println("Trying File based approach..."); //$NON-NLS-1$
        try
        {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Value was \"{0}\"", workbook.getSheetAt(0).getRow(0).getCell(0))); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if (workbook != null)
            {
                workbook.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception that is produced:

```
org.apache.poi.POIXMLException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:580)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:270)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:266)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:205)
    at com.in2.excelreader_art.DAT3983Example.main(DAT3983Example.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFactory.createDocumentPart(XSSFFactory.java:56)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:60)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to parse xml bean
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:166)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.SstDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.readFrom(SharedStringsTable.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.<init>(SharedStringsTable.java:107)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 5443012; Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.poi.util.DocumentHelper.readDocument(DocumentHelper.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader.parse(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:163)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.xerces.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 4-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: What versions of Apache POI and Apache xmlbeans are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr I've added this information to the question, apologies.

Comment: @Jakg Would doing what is suggested in the answer of this question [Read from excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39567127/while-reading-the-data-from-excel-file-with-extension-xlsx-using-apache-poi-it-t) and change the `WorkbookFactory.create(file);` to `WorkbookFactory.create(file.getExcelFile());`

Also can use Notepad to save a file as UTF-8 if needed.

Comment: @Jaybro90 I'm sorry I don't understand - I already have a `Java.io.File`, there is no `getExcelFile()` method for this (nor does one make sense).

The encoding of the `sharedStrings.xml` file is already UTF-8, I am unsure of the encoding of the original file although as it's a ZIP container I don't know what relevance this is. However, even if it was incorrect I would need to be able to fix this from within my application, not from something else.

Comment: @Jakg Check the default encoding of your IDE and see what it is set to, seems like this issue can be caused by special characters not parsing properly from google searches on this issue.

Comment: @Jaybro90 if it was down to the IDE, which would `InputStream`s work, but `File`s not?

Comment: @Jakg Try changing the try of the `InputStream` to `(InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file, "UTF-8"))`, if this gives an exception you may have to just use `InputStream` although uses more memory [Apache Doc - File vs Inputstream](http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FileInputStream)

Comment: @Jaybro90 `java.io.FileInputStream` doesn't have a constructor that takes in an encoding. In addition - it works with an in `InputStream` - so that's not the issue.

Comment: Can you try with Apache POI 4.0 (released last week) and Apache xmlbeans 3.0.1 (2-3 weeks ago), and see if it has been fixed?

Comment: @Gagravarr it works with POI 4.0.0! Unfortunately I cannot use this as it does not support Java 7. I can't see an entry in the release notes related to this issue, however?

Comment: Try just the newer xmlbeans jar then

Comment: @Gagravarr using the new XML Beans library it works, thankyou. Would you like to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer

You seem to be hitting a bug in an old version of Apache XML Beans. If you upgrade to at least [Apache XML Beans 3.0.1](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/) you should find the problem goes away.

Ideally you'd also upgrade to at least Apache POI 4.0.0, which requires the newer xmlbeans, but that requires Java 8+. XML Beans is backwards compatible, so you can stick with POI 3.17 and upgrade just xmlbeans without issue (though obviously without the POI fixes in 4!)